# Django how to get the first page of items when hitting an url?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I working on my first django application and more particulary on the pagination. Before adding the pagination when I went on:

```
http://localhost:8000/posts
```

I would have displayed me all the items.

But now I added pagination and everything work fine. I display only 2 items per pages and I've got 5 items. Everything works fine when I hit the page:

```
http://localhost:8000/posts?page=1
http://localhost:8000/posts?page=2
http://localhost:8000/posts?page=3
```

But when I hit:

```
http://localhost:8000/posts
```

I've got the following error:

```
That page number is not an integer
```

This is my view.py:

```
def posts(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.order_by('published_date')
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 2)
    page = request.GET.get("page")
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'my_blog/posts.html', context)
```

How can I get ride of this problem and when hitting: `http://localhost:8000/posts` having the first page displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the `PageNotAnInteger` exception handling, it should be `1` instead of `page`:

```
try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    posts = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
```

by

```
except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
```

Special agree